Beginner Linear optimization problem - Simplex method
I'm asked to solve the following optimization problem. So far I've only learned the simplex algorithm and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the Z value only gets worse and never gets better.
The question is:

A pound of feed A costs 0.4 dollars and a pound of feed B costs 0.8
dollars.
Bag A provides 800 calories and bag B provides 1000 calories
Bag A has 140 units of vitamins while bag B has 70
I must have at least 8000 calories a day
I must have at least 700 vitamins
No more then 1/3 of my diet can come from bag A
Minimize cost

These are what I think the equations should be:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min &  Z = 0.4A + 0.8B\\
&800A+1000B \ge 8000\\
&140A+70B \ge 700\\
&2A-B\le0
\end{array}
$$
First I got problem into standard equality form
I changed minimize to maximize by multiplying -1:
Maximize: Z = -0.4A - 0.8B $\Rightarrow$ Z+0.4A+0.8B = 0
I added a slack variable to the constraints to make them =
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
&800A+1000B - S_1 = 8000\\
&140A+70B - S_2 = 700\\
&2A-B + S_3  = 0
\end{array}
$$
At this point I set up the following tableau



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4
0.8
0
0
0
0
-------


S1
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
8000
-------


S2
0
140
70
0
-1
0
700
-------


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
-------



For my entering variable I choose A because Z is larger the smaller (0.4A+0.8B) are so maxing out A is better for that. So I calculate my ratio to determine the leaving variable



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4
0.8
0
0
0
0
-------


S1
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
8000
10


S2
0
140
70
0
-1
0
700
5


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
-------



So I determine that S2 should be the leaving variable because it has the smallest ratio. perform row operations on that row



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4
0.8
0
0
0
0
-------


S1
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
8000
---


S2
0
1
0.5
0
-1/140
0
5
---


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
-------



This is where my understanding fails to perform row operations and eliminate other values in column A I would need to subtract row S2 from them. This leads to a negative Z value since. Since I'm maximizing shouldn't RHS of the Z row only go Up? I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here any help would be appreciated.

It seems like you forgot the negativity constraints $A,B,S_1,S_2,S_3\ge0$. You'll need to use artificial variables and the Big-M method to solve this problem. Additionally, because the values of your objective function are negative after the min to max transformation, the values will appear negative for $Z$. Recall this important fact: the following objective functions are equivalent $\min f(x) = -\max -f(x)$. So multiply your final result by $-1$ at the end of the Simplex method to get your desired positive outcome.
Your initial table, before the addition of artificial variables, will look like the following:



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4
0.8
0
0
0
0
-------


?
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
8000
-------


?
0
140
70
0
-1
0
700
------


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
-------



With the addition of artificial variables, it will look like the following:



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
a1
a2
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4
0.8
0
0
0
-M
-M
0
-------


?
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
1
0
8000
-------


?
0
140
70
0
-1
0
0
1
700
------


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
0
0
-------



Once do row operations for $a_1$ and $a_2$, it will look like the following:



---
Z
A
B
S1
S2
S3
a1
a2
RHS
Ratio




Z
1
0.4-940M
0.8 -1070M
-M
-M
0
0
0
-8700M
-------


a1
0
800
1000
-1
0
0
1
0
8000
-------


a2
0
140
70
0
-1
0
0
1
700
------


S3
0
2
-1
0
0
1
0
0
0
-------



Where $M$ is an arbitrarily large number. I'll leave the working out the rest of the problem for you to do.
